# How to display a button on the video after video ends with react-player

Tags: reactjs, react-player

In my React app, I want a button to navigate to the next lesson to be appeared on the video, right after the current video is finished playing. I'm using `react-player` to display videos. I want to know how can I accomplish this is `react-player`. Any helpful tip is highly appreciated.

```js
 <ReactPlayer
          url={videoPath}
          width="100%"
          height='100%'
          controls={true}
          className="player"
          onEnded={markLessonAsCompleted}
          config={{
            file: {
              attributes: {
                controlsList: "nodownload"
              }
            }
          }}
          volume={1}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a boolean state value when the video ends (`onEnded`) and conditionally show the "next" button.
The button needs to be absolutely positioned to overlay the video. And to center the button flex box is one of many options.

The following code is also available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-fire-inuir) as a code sandbox.

```
function App() {
  const urls = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPZXk4ESdng?t=50',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcWZ6C-kn_Y'
  ]
  const [currentUrlIndex, setCurrentUrlIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const [showNextButton, setShowNextButton] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}
    >
      <ReactPlayer
        url={urls[currentUrlIndex]}
        playing
        controls
        onEnded={() => setShowNextButton(true)}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      />
      {showNextButton && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCurrentUrlIndex(
              prevUrlIndex => (prevUrlIndex + 1) % urls.length
            )
            setShowNextButton(false)
          }}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 10,
            fontSize: '2em'
          }}
        >
          next
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```